# THEAD Not repeating after certain size

Tags: html, css, pdf

I am using this to create a quotation template for our online project management software (which prints it to a PDF):

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" align="right" style="width:146px" valign="top">
      <img class="body_table img_logo" name="user:logo_url" src="/images/logo.jpg" />
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="address_details" style="font-weight:500;">
    <th align="left"><span name="job:company">{{job.company}}</span></th>
    <th align="right"><span name="user:company">{{user.company}}</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="address_details" style="font-weight:400">
    <th align="left"><span name="job:address">{{job.address}}</span></th>
    <th align="right">
      <span name="user:address">{{user.address}}</span>
      <br/>
      <span name="user:depot_email">{{user.depot_email}}</span>
      <br/>
      <span name="depot:telephone">{{depot.telephone}}</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

So it works as intended, giving repeated branding on each printed page, but as soon as the last `<span name="depot:telephone">{{depot.telephone}}</span>` is added, it stops repeating on subsequent pages. It doesn't seem to be that one line though, if I comment out another random bit, it starts working. So, I assume it's a length thing.

I am too much of a newb to HTML to know what I broke, any ideas? Is there a max length that the THEAD can be?

The stuff in the "{{xxx}}}" is what draws data from the online software.
The PDF generator options are "Webkit" which doesn't seem to do the repititions right or "Chromium", which does.

Comment: Render HTML as XML, it will tell you if there are any malformed XML parsing errors (save file as *.xhtml and open with a Gecko browser such as Waterfox). The highest priority for any and all developers are client needs, knowing all about the occurrence of any and all errors is a very close second.